# При печати или формировании PDF шрифт не жирный

Tags: css, puppeteer

При использовании puppeteer,
Текст который в браузере отображается жирным, при конвертации в PDF перестаёт быть жирным.

```
.element {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Нужно указать еще какие то css свойства для печати жирным?

Для стандартных шрифтов например Arial жирный работает.

Comment: `args: [..., '--font-render-hinting=slight']`

Comment: --font-render-hinting=slight не помогает.